# How to access xtext indexer?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, indexing, dsl, xtext

I am familiar with cdt indexer, and I expected to find something similar in xtext. But I didn't found any useful samples of code.

I want to request the xtext indexer.Let's say that my dsl langage has defined some interfaces and methods.
Having a known method name, and a list of potential dsl files:  X.dsl, Y.dsl, X.dsl 
I need to find out which one from provided list contains declaration for my method.
And all should be done in an independent eclipse plugin.

Basically, how to instantiate and to access xtext indexer ?
How to search something in my dsl files, using all projects from workspace, when the project name is not known?

Does objects  IResourceDescription, IEObjectDescription are the right wait to start from?

It would be really helpful if anyone could give me a hint how to achieve it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for org.eclipse.xtext.ui.search.IXtextEObjectSearch? This class implements the search used when you do the command "Open Model Element" (Ctrl+Shift+F3)

Comment: Thanks a lot Fabien, seems that org.eclipse.xtext.ui has some useful samples.

Answer (score 2):

The Xtext index if available from the `ResourceDescriptionsProvider`. You can inject that service and obtain the index from it.